# How to map a BitSet on facesconfig.xml

Tags: java, jsf, bitset, faces-config

I want to map this bean in my facesconfig.xml

```
public class VisualizationBean {

    private BitSet results;

    public BitSet getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(BitSet results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

}
```

As I saw in [some articles](http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/faces-config.html) and some examples, it is possible to initialize maps or other fields, but I can't figure out how to initialize this fiel. I guess something similar to

```
 <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>visualizationBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>path.bean.VisualizationBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>results</property-name>
            <map-entries>
                <map-entry>
                    <key>true</key>
                    <value>6</value>
                </map-entry>
                <map-entry>
                    <key>false</key>
                    <value>12</value>
                </map-entry>
                <map-entry>
                    <key>false</key>
                    <value>24</value>
                </map-entry>                
            </map-entries>
        </managed-property>        
    </managed-bean>
```

But htis is not correct. Any help??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The `BitSet` doesn't implement `Map` and JSF doesn't provide facilities to preset other managed property data structures than `List` or `Map`.

You have basically 2 options:

1. Use a `Map<Object, Boolean>` instead (note that you need to inverse the keys/values in your `faces-config.xml`; keys are supposed to be unique!)
2. Fill the `BitSet` yourself during bean's (post)construction based on some other external file, like a `.properties` file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation. Can I initialize using an external file, as you suggest, in the same faces-config??

Comment: Can I initialize using an external file, as you suggest, in the same faces-config??

Comment: No. Just put the file in classpath and obtain it by `Class#getResourceAsStream()`. Best what `faces-config.xml` can offer you is the ability to specify the path/name of the file in question.